# How to hide the action bar (Sherlock) inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an action bar set up in the main activity, and this creates a bunch of fragments. However, there are several fragments that require the action bar to be hidden, but I can't refer to the ActionBarSherlock class inside a fragment.

How can I hide the action bar? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you can refer to ActionBar via activity which you can get from a SherlockFragment by calling `SherlockFragment.getSherlockActivity()`, then just call `SherlockFragmentActivity.getSupportActionBar()` and then `hide()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out I was using regular Fragments, so I just used getActivity().getActionBar().hide();.